# Switch mode power supply making for beginner

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

Hi I'm a beginner at designing smps circuits tbh its my first time and i don't wanna get into the headache of using pwms and octocouplers insteas i want a mosfet or ic that can regulate itself i.e having a fixed voltage output and adjusting its switching frequency automatically according to the load added I don't really care about what ever voltage it outputs I'll add multiple of them in series just to avoid the headache of using pwms
So can anyone help me with such mosfets effecient ones are preffered and i need around 24 volts 21-24 volts

Comment: You have lots of options for this. The most easiest way is to use smps chips like LM2576, LM2577, LT1170, MT3608, LM2596, which contain all pwm/control/sense/Mosfet inside. But u will need to add some inductor, cap and resistors. You can also use chips like UC3842(a smps controller) and a separate Mosfet, but this is a bit more difficult way.

Comment: #Techecal Hadi, Yes, I agree with @Hamid R. Tanhaei that MT3608, LM2596 are good for newbies to start. I once DIYed an LM2596 SMPS and learned a lot from the project. The good thing with LM2596 is that you can easily find cheapy assembled modules as a "cheap sheet", in case you got stuck. MT3608 is step up, and assembled modules are even cheaper, and circuit even simpler. Happy making. Cheers.

Comment: Yeah I'm good with adding all the other components just want to avoid the pwm and feedback systems thanks for these options

Comment: Also if there's some chip that i can use to build a step up converter like this for example one that converts 12 vdc to 24vdc with build in pwm and feedback system

Comment: The 2576 family was called Simple Switcher after all.